# How to get the quantity of each registration type?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query:

```
 public function payment($id = "", $slug = "", $regID)
{
    $registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with(['participants.registration_type',
        'participants' => function ($query) use ($regID) {
            $query->select('id', 'registration_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $regID);
        }
    ])->find($regID);

    return view('conferences.showSummary', compact( 'registrationTypeDetails'));

}
```

To get the info(name and price) about each registration type where each participant is registered in a specific conference registration. (A registration has some participants and each participant is associated with a registration type.)

So $registrationTypeDetails shows:

```
Registration {#259 ▼
...
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#263 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Participant {#270 ▼
         ...
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#276 ▼
              ....
              #attributes: array:12 [▼
                "id" => 2
                "name" => "free"
                "price" => 0
                "conference_id" => 2
              ]
              ...
            }
          ]
         ...
        }
        1 => Participant {#272 ▼
          ...
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#278 ▼
            ...
              #attributes: array:12 [▼
                "id" => 3
                "name" => "paid"
                "price" => 1
                "conference_id," => 2
              ]
             ...
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
...
}
```

With this query results I want to show in the view the registration type name, price, quantity and subtotal. The name and price is already working with the code below.

**Doubt:** But do you know how to get the quantity and subtotal of each registration type? For example if the registration is composed of 3 participants, 2 participants registered in the registration type "general" and 1 in the registration type
 "plus" I want to show the quantity 2 for the registration type "general" and quantity 1 for the registration type "plus", like:

```
  @foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
<li class="list-group-item list-group-registration d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
    <span class="font-size-sm"> {{$participant->registration_type['name']}} </span>
    <span class="font-size-sm">{{$participant->registration_type['price']}} </span>
    <!--<span class="font-size-sm">how to show the quantity? (ex: 2) </span>-->
    <!--<span class="font-size-sm">how to show the subtotal? (ex: 4$)</span>-->
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: John, I don't think the overall schema for the loop works.  You are looping on participants, the participant has ONE registration type.  The quantity will always be one for that participant.  If you are looking for total quantity, shouldn't this be displayed outside the loop of participants?  I think perhaps you would want to collect registration types and loop on that, then take the participants from that object.  So you'd have Type General: total 5, participants using this type: John, Tim, Bill.  Then, subtotal within the type.  No?

Comment: Thanks, yes maybe is not possible with the foreach. Can you explain better that part of collect the participants from that object? I want to achieve that result, the registration type name, the price, quantity and subtotal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand: you are trying to show a running total of registration types by *participant*, and show the sub total count of those registration types as you go down the page.  If you don't want to change the loop to loop on the registration type, I think you can do this:

I would recommend keeping the query you have and create a couple of variables in the controller just for registration types counts, and send that also from the controller to the view.

```
$general_type_count = 0;
$plus_type_count = 0;
foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p){
    if($p->registration_type['name'] === 'general')
       $general_type_count ++;
    if($p->registration_type['name'] === 'plus')
       $plus_type_count ++;
}
```

Once you have the registration types count in the view, add variables at the top of the loop to count each type as we hit one (this will be the subtotal for the type).  This is not great separation of code from the view... but it is pretty bullet proof:

```
<?php $plus = 0; $general = 0; ?>
@foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-registration d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
    <span class="font-size-sm"> {{$participant->registration_type['name']}} </span>
    <span class="font-size-sm">{{$participant->registration_type['price']}} </span>
    <span class="font-size-sm">
        @if($participant->registration_type['name'] === 'general')
           {{$general_type_count}}
        @endif
        @if($participant->registration_type['name'] === 'plus')
           {{$plus_type_count}}
        @endif
    </span>
   <?php 
     // Running count in view for subtotals
     if($participant->registration_type['name'] === 'general') 
        $general++;
     if($participant->registration_type['name'] === 'plus') 
        $plus++;
   ?>
    <span class="font-size-sm">{{$$participant->registration_type['name']}}</span>
   // Using a variable variable above to be simpler, but it is basically just calling $general or $plus based on the name of the type
  </li>
@endforeach
```

The above is VERY drawn-out, just to explain one way to get what you need; you can make this much tighter for sure.  It is also the most basic way of doing this and gets ugly if you have more than a few types of registrations -- you can surely improve this, but I don't know what your controllers look like.  If you have some kind of reverse relationship on the participants or types table, or better yet, a many-to-many on the top level Registrations model, perhaps you can do this all in a single query without the loop.  Take a look at the [withCount() method from laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) as a possibility.

Comment: Thanks, but the registration type names "general" and "plus" were just an example. A registration type can have any name, the user  that creates a conference can create registration tyes with any name.

Comment: OK, I understand.  Its hard to do running tallies when the type can have any name, as you don't have any control.  It is still possible, using the above.  You can make an array for types and loop through in the controller.  Each time you have a new type, you add that type as a key for the array, and up the count for that array index.  E.g. $rTypes['xxx'] ++ $rTypes['yyy'] ++, etc.  You can then get creative on the view to check against the *index* in similar format to my answer.  Not cleanest approach.  Best way may be to add a relationship to a class (or new class) and use the withCount().

Comment: Thanks, add a relationship to a class, that is, to a model?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Think about this - if you had the registration types on the registration, and not the participant, you could pretty easily count what you needed to per your view above.  This would perhaps mean creating a registration_registration_type pivot table, and you'd have to attch many instead of just adding one type to the participant, but you would then have access to the counts at the top level (registration) and be able to loop through them, instead of having to bolt on the variables like in my answer.  Then, it would just be a foreach loop and wouldn't matter how many types you had.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also means changing around your schema if you still want to track by participant AND registration for the types, but from your needs, it looks like you maybe wanted to have that on the registration to begin with.  If you need to track by participant, you can always make that relationship too (or leave as is, and just ADD the many-to-many on the registration, thus allowing you to count like you want)

Comment: Thanks again really. I'm a beginner maybe is simpler the method without changing the db schema. Can you just explain better this part "and up the count for that array index."? Im not achieving that part, I can store the registration type names as keys like " foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $rtypeDetails){
            $registrationTypes += [
                $rtypeDetails->registration_type['name'] => 1
            ];
        }". But Im not understanding how to get the correct quantity.

Comment: Because in your example with static general and plus values you can do like "                                        if($p->registration_type['name'] === 'general')
" and increment, but in this case the name can be any so Im not understanding how to achieve that.

Comment: It gets pretty ugly... but what I meant was something like: foreach($rTD->participants as $p) { if isset ($array[$p->typeName]) $array[$p->typeName] ++ else $array[$p->typeName] =1;  }    This is not great but would work with some tweaking.  Instead, better to add many-to-many on the Registration class for types, and then you can check independent of the participant model.  I think easier :) And it gets you what you want - you can even leave the participant->type on there, and have two relationships if you want.  Based on your view, you probably want the many-to-many on the Registration model.

Comment: Thanks again really! I will check if I can achieve that solution using eloquent, so is necessary to create a many to many between RegistrationType and Registration. In the Registration model I add: "public function registration_types(){ return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_registration_types');}". In the RegistrationType model I add: public function registrations(){ return $this->belongsToMany('App\Registration', 'registration_registration_types'); }}"

Comment: Thanks again really! I will check if I can achieve that solution using eloquent, so is necessary to create a many to many between RegistrationType and Registration. In the Registration model I add: "public function registration_types(){ return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_registration_types');}". In the RegistrationType model I add: public function registrations(){ return $this->belongsToMany('App\Registration', 'registration_registration_types'); }}". And is not necessary to create any pivot table right?

Comment: You would need 1 pivot table - registration_registration_type.  This is so you can attach as many types to the registration as you want.  Play with this -- you now have 2 ways to do what you wanted, but you will have to work with it to make it function and to understand how to use it as you best need.  Your model methods look fine.  I think this is a cleaner way to go than the variable approach.  Adding the relation to the Registration is a change to your original overall program path, but it will directly help you get the view the way you want it with the total & subtotals.